# how can i bring data from static websites to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, spring-xd, flume-twitter

What are the other available framework like spring XD, Flume for that? Which one is the best among; please advise steps to bring data.

Comment: What Are the steps i need to follow to get data in hdfs from static site.
I am having kafka in cloudera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using NUTCH
- Using Kafka flume
- Using spring xd
- **scraper** import.io
- java program by producer consumer